# Julia code: Is it possible to force a function to **require** only one of several **named** "optional" inputs?

Tags: julia

*Edit: The original question has been modified a bit:*

I have a very good reason to make a single function that accepts (two) named optional variables which are not independent of each other, meaning that if you set one - you get the other, and vice-versa. As input though, only one and exactly one has to be provided (and the other is derived).
All input arguments are of the same type, so simply dispatching by type won't help.

Here is a schematic pseudocode/idea of the problem, given that I don't have a MWE that I can provide:

```
    function testfun(req1, req2 ; namedopt1, namedopt2)
    # namedopt2=req1+req2+namedopt1 or namedopt1=namedopt2-req1-req2

        if <namedopt1 AND namedopt2 are given>
            ERROR!
        elseif <opt1 is given>
            namedopt2=req1+req2+namedopt1
            return namedopt2
        elseif <namedopt2 is given>
            namedopt1=namedopt2-req1-req2
            return namedopt1
        else
            ERROR!
        end # if

    end # function
```

Assume that the inputs `req1,req2,opt1,opt2` are all of the same type. `req1,req2` are given anyway, just to have some "meat" there, while EITHER `namedopt1,namedopt2` should be provided, but not both.
Is it possible to have such a functionality in Julia without making a big issue out of it?

Extra question:
Is it possible to do the check in compilation (so `val{}` kind of thing)?

Note: I understand that the if/else combo is probably stupid and I should do something on the lines of `if <namedopt1 .AND. namedopt2> then ERROR` to cover thing more efficiently. But I wanted the question to be as clear and simple as possible.

Comment: Perhaps Named variables would be a better decription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this with the type system and multiple dispatch:

```
struct NamedOpt1{T}
value::T
end

struct NamedOpt2{T}
value::T
end

function testfun(req1, req2, namedopt1::NamedOpt1)::NamedOpt2 ... end
function testfun(req1, req2, namedopt2::NamedOpt2)::NamedOpt1 ... end

x = testfun(x, y, NamedOpt1(val))
```

Now overloads only exist for the three-argument versions, and dispatch will be done based on type.

Comment: In the real case I actually need multiple optional arguments, but after thinking about it, I think I can do a set of these using pairs in each multiple dispatch and do them one after the other.

Answer (score 2):

Well you're close. Typically in most programming or scripting languages the idea is to check versus a `null`, `nul`, `nil`, `nullptr` and so on. JavaScript went as far as creating a scenario for `undefined` values.

For JC, it's pretty much straight forward, with its keyword being `nothing`.

There are some caveats here, such as interpreting `==` vs `===` (and similarly `!=` vs `!==`). I recommend you read about them, but the gist of it is that `==` and `!=` check for equality, while `===` and  `!==` check for similarity.

Also note that an optimal way of checking for null is using the `isnothing` helper. This requires at least version 1.1 though.

You can even try `notnothing()`.

To report an error, you can use the... well, `error()` function.

In this case:

```
if (notnothing(opt1) && notnothing(opt2))
    error("You can't assign both optional params")
```

Considering you don't have a MWE, this should steer you in the right direction.

Comment: They can't be nothing, because they require at the very least some default value, otherwise you get a compilation error.

Comment: I have modified the question slightly, maybe take another look at it?

Comment: @TheWhitestOfFangs You can set the default value to be `nothing` and then check for this. I am _not_, however, familiar with any `notnothing` function. You can use `isnothing` and `!isnothing`